# Clearing a list without clearing the same list which is inside another list

Tags: python

```py
test = list()
test2 = list()
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    
    
for number in numbers:
   test.append(number) 
   if len(test) >= 3:
        test2.append(test)
    
   test.clear()
```

So I want to clear `test` after I appended it to `test2` but when I do so the list inside `test2` gets also cleared how can I avoid that?

so they look like that after clear:

```py
test = []
test2 = []
```

but I want `test2` to be `[["1", "2", "3"]]`

Comment: You can use the list.copy function so you append a copy of test to test2.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy

Comment: You will have to append a copy instead of a reference to the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the version of the list that you don't want to delete.

```
test = list()
test2 = list()
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]


for number in numbers:
   test.append(number) 
   if len(test) >= 3:
     test2.append(test[:]) # This grabs a slice of the entire list, effectively copying it

test.clear()
```

Comment: For basic questions like this, you should look to see if there's a duplicate first before answering - please see the section on answering "well-asked questions" here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer